# Wordpress admin side slow

Tags: wordpress, performance, plugins, admin, pagespeed

I prefer to use `WP Super Cache` on large websites, it provides good loading times for the front-end. I regularly use `WPML`, `Wishlist`, few sliders and some other small plugins. in that case WP Super Cache works good on the front end but the back-end is getting very slow.

anybody have any suggestion about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue a few weeks ago. The problem occurred by the .htaccess file. Disable the cache plugin, reset your htaccess (look @ wordpress codex how to) and test your backend.

If it works, try to reinstall super cache or another cache plugin. Your current plugin might cause issues with your theme or installed plug-ins.

Goodluck!

Comment: i have tried that... check without cache plugin. its the same. wp super cache enable or disabled.. front end is caching perfectly, but wp-admin is really slow. i am looking solution for wp-admin speed.

Comment: Already reset the .htaccess? Hmm... Sounds like a malfunctioning plug-in to me... Have you tried to disable all the installed plug-ins?

Comment: if disabled all the plugins ofcourse wp-admin speed is good as normal. are you sure what i am looking for... front pages are perfect with the cache. but i am looking for the wp-admin speed issues.

Comment: Yes... Disable all plugins and activate them one by one. If you know which plugins causes the error we might be able to help you further.